# jQuery slideDown menu won't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the same trouble that I have last week.

My html code looks like this:

```
<article class="tickets">
                <div class="grid_12 left">
                    <div class="header">
                        <i class="icon-pushpin"></i>
                        Neue Tickets
                        <div class="count right"><span>6</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="messages">
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="header">
                        <i class="icon-pushpin"></i>
                        Neue Tickets
                        <div class="count right"><span>6</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="messages">
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
```

and the jQuery part:

```
$('.header').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.messages').slideDown(500);
    $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The first menu slide's down and up and the second menu down. 
I would slideDown the first menu and after a click on the "header" a slideUp. When the first menu is open and you I click on the second menu the first menu should slideUp and the second down.
What is wrong with my Code?

Comment: jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Evolutio/tpzmZ/

Comment: The messages are slideing down, but at the sametime they slide Up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$(this).siblings('.messages').not($(this).next('.messages')).slideUp(500);
$(this).next('.messages').slideToggle('normal');
```

First, I am sliding up all the `.message`'s (EXCEPT `$(this).next('.messages')`), then I am toggling `$(this).next('.messages')`. I have used toggle so that you can close as well as open it.

I have updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpzmZ/3/)

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - .not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.messages').hide();



clickme=function(){

$('.header').click(function(e) {

    $(this).siblings('.messages').slideDown(500);
    $(this).off('click');
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.messages').slideUp('normal');
    })
        $(this).on('click',clickme);    
});
}
clickme();
```

try this!